# Monitoring Tomcat via JMX

Tags: tomcat, monitoring, catalina

We have the challenge to monitor some Tomcats via JMX (and finally via Monitis via the JMX connection).

Tomcat exposes multiple MBean attributes via JMX, but I cannot find any documentation or even an overview about the attributes and their meaning. I can guess some meanings, but I don´t think that´s the best way to do it.
So, are there any listings or descriptions about the exposed attributes?

We´re looking for the classic things like memory consumption, request throughput etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have looked here https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Monitoring?
There is some information there about basic metrics you might want to monitor

Comment: Thanks, but sadly that´s not very detailed. Do you know a more comprehensive overview?